# Analytic function with prescribed zeroes of first derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a sequence of distinct values $(a_n)$ with no limit point, by using Weierstrass's Product Theorem and Mittag-Leffler Theorem, we are able to specify an entire function $f$ where $f(a_n)=c_n$ for our choice of $c_n$.

In addition to the above condition, how can we find an entire function whereby the $f$ also satisfies $f'(a_n)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is false. If $a_n=\frac 1 n$ and $c_n=n$ we cannot have an entire function $f$ with $f(a_n)=c_n$ for all $n$.

If the assume that $(a_n)$ has no limit point then the result is true. In this case we can pre-assign values of $f$ and its derivatives up to a any given order arbitrarily. The existence of such a function is proved in Rudin's RCA:
 See the section 'An Interpolation Problem' in the chapter on 'Zeros of Analytic Functions'.

Comment: Thanks. Edited.